COMplus service on windows container
Is it possible to deploy complus service on AKS windows container ?
I tried looking around online, but didn't find much information! Hence posting here

Deploying COM+ services in Windows containers on AKS is quite challenging and non-standard, but if you have the dockerfile available with you I can try to guide you. You will need a Dockerfile to build your Windows container image.  Deploy your aks cluster and create a deployment.yaml that specifies your complus Docker image. I will share below an example Dockerfile which assumes you have a COM+ DLL that needs to be registered with regsvr32. Modify paths and filenames according to your application. Fix the indentation in your editor since I am pasting in comments.

`# Use an appropriate Windows base image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
Set the shell to PowerShell for easier scripting
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';"]
Copy your COM+ application files to the container
COPY ./ComPlusApplication /ComPlusApplication
Register your COM+ application (adjust script as needed)
RUN New-Object -ComObject COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog 
| Start-Process -FilePath 'regsvr32' -ArgumentList '/s', '/c', 'C:\ComPlusApplication\YourComPlus.dll' -NoNewWindow -Wait`

This is great - Thank you @Arko- Let me get started with this information and update you how it goes !!

As discussed over comments, You will need a Dockerfile to build your Windows container image.
mkdir MyComPlusApp
cd MyComPlusApp


Copy all necessary files for your COM+ application into this directory. This includes DLLs, configuration files, and any scripts needed for installation or setup.
example
# Use an appropriate Windows base image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

# Set the shell to PowerShell for easier scripting
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';"]

# Copy your COM+ application files to the container
COPY ./ComPlusApplication /ComPlusApplication

# Register your COM+ application (adjust script as needed)
RUN New-Object -ComObject COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog \
    | Start-Process -FilePath 'regsvr32' -ArgumentList '/s', '/c', 'C:\ComPlusApplication\YourComPlus.dll' -NoNewWindow -Wait

This Dockerfile assumes you have a COM+ DLL that needs to be registered with regsvr32. Modify paths and filenames according to your application.
Build the Docker image with the following command:
docker build -t yourregistry/yourcomplusapp:latest .


Push the image to your container registry (e.g., Azure Container Registry):
docker push yourregistry/yourcomplusapp:latest

Ensure your AKS cluster is configured with a Windows node pool since COM+ is a Windows-specific technology. f you haven't already, create an AKS cluster with a Windows node pool using Azure CLI:
az aks create \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --name myAKSCluster \
  --node-count 1 \
  --enable-addons monitoring \
  --kubernetes-version 1.18.14 \
  --generate-ssh-keys \
  --windows-admin-username azureuser \
  --windows-admin-password myP@ssw0rd123 \
  --vm-set-type VirtualMachineScaleSets \
  --load-balancer-sku standard \
  --network-plugin azure

Add a Windows Server node pool to your AKS cluster:
az aks nodepool add \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --cluster-name myAKSCluster \
  --os-type Windows \
  --name npwin \
  --node-count 1 \
  --kubernetes-version 1.18.14

Create a Kubernetes deployment YAML file (deployment.yaml) that specifies your Docker image:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: complus-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: complus-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: complus-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: complus-container
        image: yourregistry/yourcomplusapp:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      nodeSelector:
        "kubernetes.io/os": windows

and apply kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml

Since running COM+ applications in containers can be unpredictable, use Kubernetes logs and other debugging tools to monitor the container's behavior. This setup is largely experimental and might not support all COM+ features or configurations

I have marked this as answer and I am trying with my application.:) Thanks again
